# how to put img inside circle in html and css?

Tags: html, css

Image should be inside the circle and circle should have white background.

and Image size should be less than the circle and in center.

I try this:

```css
.icon i {
  color: #fff;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 15%;
}
```

```html
<li><a href="#"><i class="icon" style="background: red;"> <img src="http://www.pngdot.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Free_Arrow_Png_01.png"  style="width:50px;height:45px;"></i></a></li>
```

Comment: What you have done so far?

Comment: `.icon` doesn't refer to anything

Comment: There should be `img` after `i`, e.g. `i img {...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly can use `border-radius` for the circle.

```css
body {
  background:#000;  
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

i {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius:50%;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
}

img {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<i><img src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/410.svg" width="30" /></i>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

**CSS**

```
body{
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

figure{
    display:block;
    width:50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    line-height: 1.7em;
}

figure img{
   display:inline-block;
   width: 30px;
   height: auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<li>
  <a href="#">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://www.pngdot.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Free_Arrow_Png_01.png" alt="image">
    </figure>
  </a>
</li>
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/132/)**

Answer (score 1):

You do not need **icon element** for any purpose.
So, you can achieve asked with following HTML:

```html
<li>
  <a href="#" id="circle"></a>
</li>
```

DEMO: [CLICK](https://jsfiddle.net/eftqtLhr/8/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the container div or i which have a radius and image content  should be overflow hidden

```
i{ 
  overflow:hidden;
}
```